# iOS Enterprise Distribution - multiple people

Tags: ios, code-signing

I have an iOS Enterprise Account, and I currently use HockeyApp for OTA app distribution. When I want to send an app to HockeyApp that utilizes this license, I make an in-house distribution profile for the app, archive it, and upload the file to HockeyApp, and it works fine. I am the agent of my team on the developer portal.

I want for other members of my team (including a Jenkins instance) to be able to sign applications with the same type of distribution profile that they can make. However, when someone tries to archive an app with the same distribution profile, they are unable to do so. Further, they are unable to apply for a distribution certificate unless they send me the `.certSigningRequest` file and I apply for it myself, then send it to them (I know this is incorrect but this seems like the only way to get them a certificate).

Basically, what do I need to do to enable another team member to archive an app for enterprise distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you'll have to export your certificate and private key from Keychain Access and have others (including the Jenkins machine) import it into their keychain.

See: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20122?locale=en_US

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I have a feeling this will work, just need to test it out with a member of the team tomorrow. I'll let you know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - it's sad that we just now got around to it, but this worked. Thanks!